# setNeedsDisplay is submitted on main queue but is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, setneedsdisplay, dispatch-async

The method below is called on a non-main thread, to be specific, in a recording audio queue callback

```
- (void)myMethod
{
//...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [myGraphView setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectMake(a, b, c, d)];
    NSLog(@"Block called");
});
//...
}
```

where myGraphView is a custom UIView object. For what I know, `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` should be called on main thread which is why I have `dispatch_async...` in place. Now the problem is the method `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` I implemented for myGraph is never called even though the `NSLog` in the block has been called for many times.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities here.

From the Class Reference:

> Note: If your view is backed by a CAEAGLLayer object, this method has
>   no effect. It is intended for use only with views that use native
>   drawing technologies (such as UIKit and Core Graphics) to render their
>   content.

The other option, which is probably the cause in this case, has to do with the actual geometry. If the provided rectangle is invalid or off screen, the call does nothing. I would suggest you verify the that the rectangle is being calculated as it should be.

Comment: I did follow your second possibility but I found the problem was caused by a third possibility that the view I wanted to update had never been added to its superview (thus never got displayed). But your answer did led me to find out the bug in my code. Thanks!

Comment: If you found the solution, please post it so that others may learn from your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Neal's answer which led me to find out that `myGraphView` was, after it had been alloc-inited the first time, alloc-inited again. However, unlike the first alloc-init after which I added `myGraphView` to its superview, I forgot to do so after the second alloc-init.

The lesson I've learned here is that when a view is not doing what it's expected to do, such as not being displayed or updated, always check this third possibility where you forget to add it back to its superview after it's got alloc-inited again somewhere in your code. Also, if the view has a delegate you would tend to forget to set it as well.